# Liquibase to automatically track (generate changelogs) from manual changes to my JPA entity classes

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm fairly new to Spring, JPA, Hibernate, Liquibase... but I'm trying to employ Liquibase so I can have my database in sync with manual changes I apply to my entity classes over time. Also, I am hoping for Liquibase being able to apply db schema updates with the existing data stay in tact (is this possible at all)?

At this stage, I have one entity class with 3 columns and it does get created at the application start. Also, another table is added via a Liquibase changelog file (but there's no entity class for it - it's just a test to see if Liquibase would generate the table at all).

This is what I have in my `pom.xml` that pertains to Hibernate & Liquibase:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now, I am aware that both **Maven Liquibase** and **Liquibase-Hibernate5** plugins exist. But how do I employ any of those since I'm using Spring Boot and most of the things are auto-configured?

***UPDATE:*** It seems that **liquibase-hibernate5** is what I need because it enables `diff`ing the current database schema against JPA/Hibernate mappings.
However, I'm yet to dive into it and try to make it work. As with anything, this plugin is not without issues so I'm starting to wonder if it's worth the hassle given that we're talking about just a couple of databases to keep in sync.

Comment: HOW COME none of Java/Spring/Hibernate have a migration tool that is capable of automatically catching changes in the model and applying them to the database. That is what I just realized about Liquibase - the developer is supposed to manually write a ChangeSet and also edit the model accordingly. That is not what I thought Liquibase does.